# Conditional probability and random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory

How do i solve this problem? i understand this involves conditional probability but I'm not sure how to begin

On a flight from Urbana to Paris my luggage did not arrive with me. It had been transferred three times and the probabilities that the transfer was not done in time were estimated to be 4/10, 2/10, 1/10, respectively, in the order of transfer. What is the probability that the first airline goofed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $N$ be the event that the luggage did not arrive, and let $G$ be the event that the first airline goofed. We want $\Pr(G|N)$. The standard useful procedure for dealing with such problems is to use the *defining formula* for conditional probability, namely
$$\Pr(G|N)=\frac{\Pr(G\cap N)}{\Pr(N)}.$$
We need the two probabilities on the right-hand side.

The probability of $G\cap N$ is essentially given to us: It is $\frac{4}{10}$.

To find $\Pr(N)$, note that it is easier to find first the probability that the luggage **did** arrive. This is the probability that nobody messed up, which is $\frac{6}{10}\cdot\frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac{9}{10}$.

Comment: Did you actually try using Andre's method? It does evaluate to 400/568

Comment: Keep in mind that $Pr(N) = 1-\frac{6}{10}\cdot \frac{8}{10}\cdot \frac{9}{10}$

Comment: Since this was homework, I left a little for you to do. From the answer, the probability the luggage arrives is $\frac{432}{1000}$. so the probability it does not arrive, that is, $\Pr(N)$, is $1-\frac{432}{1000}$, which is $\frac{568}{1000}$. Divide $\frac{4}{10}$ by this. We get $\frac{4000}{5680}$, which can be simplified in various ways.

Answer (score 0):

HINT: Use Bayes' theorem. http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bayes'_theorem